Restate equality between random variables in a numerical stable way
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables drawn from two distinct normal distributions, $\mathcal{N} (\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $\mathcal{N} (\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$, that correspond to the measurements of an experiment at time $t$, with $\sigma$ as the uncertainties of the measurement, $\approx 0.01\mu$.
In each timestep, we measure a single value for $X$ and $Y$, with both $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ varying with time.
I want to check if the following property holds: $$ \mu_X^2(t) - \mu_X(t) \mu_Y(t) = K , \forall t. $$
Since $\sigma / \mu \ll 1$, one can approximate the distribution from which $XY$ is drawn as $\mathcal{N}(\mu_X \mu_Y, \mu_X^2 \sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2 \sigma_X^2)$ and the distribution from which $X^2$ is drawn as $\mathcal{N}(\mu_X^2, 4\mu_X^2 \sigma_X^2)$.
This variance is very large, and I cannot verify if $K$ is is fact constant. The first approach I considered (smash the $X$ and $Y$ variances) is not available since we can only make a single measurement at any time.
Since I am only interested in the existence of the relation (and not in the value of $K$), is there a way to restate the equality in order for it to yield a constant value with smaller variance?

If the $\mu_X(t)$ and $\mu_Y(t)$ are bounded for all values of $t$, we may try to construct a statistic that has a mean of $\mu_X(t)^2 - \mu_X(t)\mu_Y(t)$ for all $t$. Under the hypothesis, this mean will be equal to $K$ for all $t$ and a data splitting strategy may help us test the hypothesis, even if the variance of the statistic varies in $t$.
If you divide the measurements (each at a different time point) into two groups, the sample means of those two groups will be $K$ (under the hypothesis) and, even if $K$ is unknown, they should be equal to one another other. As the number of observations in each group gets bigger, the variance of the sample mean for each group can be driven to zero and the hypothesis that the two groups have the same mean can be tested. This could be done for several random divisions of the data.
Concretely, consider $(X_t - Y_t)X_t$. It's mean is $\mu_X(t)^2 - \mu_X \mu_Y + \sigma_X(t)^2$. It was stated in the problem, however, that $\sigma_X(t) = \omega \mu_X(t)$ for $\omega = 0.01$. Therefore, consider $(X_t - Y_t)X_t - \omega^2 X_t Y_t$. Because the $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent, $E(X_t Y_t)= \mu_x \mu_y$ and we find that
$$
E ((X_t - Y_t)X_t - \omega^2 X_t Y_t ) = \mu_X(t)^2 - \mu_X \mu_Y + \omega^2 \mu_X(t)^2 - \omega^2 \mu_X(t) \mu_Y(t),\\
=(1+\omega^2) (\mu_X(t)^2 - \mu_X(t) \mu_Y(t)),
$$
which is equal to $(1+\omega^2)K$ for all $t$ under the hypothesis.

How can $(\mu_X (t) - \mu_Y (t))(\mu_X (t) + \mu_Y (t))$ be always constant from my condition? Did you mean $(\mu_X (t) - \mu_Y (t))(\mu_X (t))$?

Ah, sorry, I read the one subscript wrong. I still suspect that something about checking for equivalence of means of two partitions could work. If I sort it out, I'll edit my answer.

It does make sense, I will try it out.

$$
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E\big((X_t-Y_t)X_t \big) \
= {} & \operatorname E\left( X_t^2\right) - \operatorname E\left( X_t Y_t \right) \
= {} & \left( (\mu_X(t))^2 + (\sigma_X(t))^2\right) - \operatorname E(X_t)\operatorname E(Y_t) \
= {} & \left( (\mu_X(t))^2 + (\sigma_X(t))^2\right) - \mu_X(t)\mu_Y(t) \
= {} & \big(\mu_X(t) - \mu_Y(t)\big)\mu_X(t) + (\sigma_X(t))^2 \
\ne {} & \big(\mu_X(t) - \mu_Y(t)\big)\mu_X(t).
\end{align}
$$

Michael Hardy is correct of course, if irritatingly terse. I'd be curious (and will try a bit more) to concoct a test statistic that has the desired mean of $K$ under the hypothesis, which would salvage the data-splitting idea.

OK, I gave it one last try, but maybe I botched it again.
